# twisted: no exception trace if error from a callback

Tags: python, error-handling, twisted, deferred

Consider the following code:

```
df = defer.Deferred()
def hah(_): raise ValueError("4")
df.addCallback(hah)
df.callback(hah)
```

When it runs, that exception just gets eaten. Where did it go? How can I get it to be displayed? Doing `defer.setDebugging(True)` has no effect.

I ask this because other times, I get a printout saying "Unhandled error in Deferred:". How do I get that to happen in this case? I see that if I add an errback to `df` then the errback gets called with the exception, but all I want to do is print the error and do nothing else, and I don't want to manually add that handler to every deferred I create.

Comment: Which twisted version are you using?

Comment: @Jacob: 8.1.0 with other extraneous characters added because of the minimum comment size limit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception is still sitting in the Deferred.  There are two possible outcomes at this point:

- You could add an errback to the Deferred.  As soon as you do, it will get called with a Failure containing the exception that was raised.
- You could let the Deferred be garbage collected (explicitly delete `df`, or return from the function, or lose the reference in any other way).  This triggers the ''Unhandled error in Deferred'' code.

Because an errback can be added to a Deferred at any time (ie, the first point above), Deferreds don't do anything with otherwise unhandled errors right away.  They don't know if the error is really unhandled, or just unhandled so far.  It's only when the Deferred is garbage collected that it can be sure no one else is going to handle the exception, so that's when it gets logged.

In general, you want to be sure you have errbacks on Deferreds, precisely because it's sometimes hard to predict when a Deferred will get garbage collected.  It might be a long time, which means it might be a long time before you learn about the exception if you don't have your own errback attached.

This doesn't have to be a terrible burden.  Any Deferred (a) which is returned from a callback on another Deferred (b) (ie, when chaining happens) will pass its errors along to b.  So (a) doesn't need extra errbacks on it for logging and reporting, only (b) does.  If you have a single logical task which is complicated and involves many asynchronous operations, it's almost always the case that all of the Deferreds involved in those operations should channel their results (success or failure) to one main Deferred that represents the logical operation.  You often only need special error handling behavior on that one Deferred, and that will let you handle errors from any of the other Deferreds involved.